# How could a word 'none' be translated when it is located at the very last end of the sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was reading a book on the novel by J.R.R. Tolkien. And Here comes the sentence with a word 'none' at its tail.

" As for any inner meaning or “message,” it has in the intention of the author none. "

please help me to get it. what's the usage of 'none'? why does it exist at its last end of the sentence?

Comment: It's just a re-ordering of "... In the intention of the author, it has none.": "Inner meanings or 'messages'? As far as I'm concerned, there are none." (But Tolkien would re-order for optimum emphasis on what he wanted emphasising and for other stylistic reasons.)

Comment: Sorry to point this out and I suggest you were not reading “a book on the novel by J.R.R. Tolkien” for the obvious reason that Tolkien wrote more than novel. Does that make sense?

To suggest that “… for any inner meaning” or “… message,” it has in the intention of (Tolkien) none" is to misunderstand both him and the grammar involved. 

Could you re-phrase what you’re asking, please:

Comment: Punctuation: || As for any inner meaning or “message,” it has, in the intention of the author, none. ||That is the punctuation that should be in the book. You were reading a book about a Tolkien novel, weren't you?

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, Edwin Ashworth wrote:

> It's just a re-ordering of "... In the intention of the author, it has none.": "Inner meanings or 'messages'? As far as I'm concerned, there are none." (But Tolkien would re-order for optimum emphasis on what he wanted emphasising and for other stylistic reasons.)